# Android - How to modify xml file in res

Tags: java, android, xml, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard

I have searched a lot and could not find the solution for that.

The thing is that I am making a Custom Keyboard. I have an XML file for the layout of this custom keyboard, stored in res/xml.

The problem is, that I want to change the keyboard layout from the java code. For that, I need to Open the xml file from res/xml/qwerty.xml and edit it with DOM In the Java Code.

How can I do it? And if it isn't possible how can I build such a keyboard that I can change dynamically through out the java code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `How can I do it?` You **can't**. Resource files are programmatically immutable.

Comment: ok, thanks... but do you know a way of doing such a dynamically keyboard?

Comment: Google: `android change keyboard layout programmatically`

Comment: I couldn't find the solution for it..

Comment: Then I can't help you.

Comment: which keyboard dynamically and show me xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely You can change our keypad dynamically.
But you Must to specify our row and column static.

Try to change key value label in this way and u can also change primaryCode value is same way:

```
            if (rflag== 1) {
                mQwertyKeyboard.getKeys().get(29).label = "NewTag";
                rflag = 0;
            } else {
                rflag = 1;
                mQwertyKeyboard.getKeys().get(29).label = "OldTag";                 

            }
```

Comment: Nice.. But how can I make my rows and cols static? also, do you mean I need to make my java keyboard service static? and can I change the keyboard from outside the service of the custom keyboard?